# Can't access Neo4j REST url on Heroku

Tags: heroku, neo4j

I am trying to use an Ajax call from my web app (not running on Heroku) to query a Neo4j installation on Heroku. The Ajax works flawlessly (no errors, expected JSON response) when connecting to my localhost server url at `http://localhost:7474/db/data`
but fails when connecting to the Heroku server url at `http://login:password@dc02bc2c6.hosted.neo4j.org:7322/db/data`

When I say "fail," I mean I receive no errors or results (monitoring in Firebug console). However, I can access the Neo4j webadmin console on Heroku (using Chrome or Firefox but not IE) using the following `http://login:password@dc02bc2c6.hosted.neo4j.org:7322/webadmin/`

The Ajax code is below.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong and how to connect to Heroku?

```
restServerURL = "http://login:password@dc02bc2c6.hosted.neo4j.org:7322/db/data";

$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: restServerURL + "/cypher",
  crossDomain: true, //recommended by Neo4j (no effect)
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
  query:"START n = node(*) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)" + request.term + ".*' RETURN n, n.name ORDER BY LOWER(n.name) ASC LIMIT 12", //"like" (=~) search term, case insensitive ((?i)), show first 12 results
        },
   success: function( data ) {
        //process json here       
        };
    }
 });
```

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Your query will be quite slow/expensive as it is a global graph scan, should use index lookups instead

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
   xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
   },
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Converting my queries to Index lookups is next on the list. I may try the xhrFields parameter. However, with the imminent release of Neo4j 2.0, the Heroku hosted version will be 2 versions behind. To that end, I set up an Amazon AWS 64-bit AMI Linux instance, successfully installed the Neo4j V1.9.2 Community Edition and connected my web app to it. This appears to be much more flexible solution than Heroku given that I have root access. I can now install the latest Neo4j version, developer tools etc. If anyone wants to know how to do this, let me know.

Comment: Tried xhrFields - no difference. At this point I am no longer looking at Heroku. On to index lookups. Thanks for your help.